# How to start an Activity or Service from smartwatch

Tags: java, android, wear-os

I have tried using wearablelistener services, but they seem to be deprecated.

Here is my current code:

```
public void lockdevice(View view) {
  Intent intent = new Intent();
  intent.setClass(this, MainActivity.class);
  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  RemoteIntent.startRemoteActivity(this, intent,null);
}
```

It creates an exception:

```
Only android.intent.action.VIEW action is currently supported for starting a remote activity
```

But a View action won't help me much. Are there any other ways to do this?

Answer (score 3):

I achieved it the following way. In you handheld `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<intent-filter>
    <data android:scheme="appname" android:host="openfromwear" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
</intent-filter>
```

In your Wear app:

```
val intentAndroid = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
  .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE)
  .setData(Uri.parse("appname://openfromwear"))
RemoteIntent.startRemoteActivity(context, intentAndroid, null)
```

Answer (score -1):

`WearableListenerService` isn't deprecated. It is still the recommended superclass for a `Service` on the handheld to be started from the linked wearable. Once your `Service` starts, you can easily launch an `Activity` from there if desired.

It's well documented here: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/events.html

Comment: WearableListenerService cannot be reached on android 11 upwards..