# How to launch an application on wearOS device on a button click from the mobile companion app?

Tags: android, wear-os

I am trying to launch an application (say app-1) on the WearOS device when a button is clicked in my mobile(Android mobile) companion app. In my use case, I should be able to launch the application which is already installed on the wearOS device(watch), from my mobile with just a button click.

I search on google and took ChatGPT's help. The solutions which are suggested are by using Wearable APIs, or by using Android Device Policy Controller (DPC) APIs. These above suggested methods require an application code on wearOS device which handles the messages sent by the mobile and performs necessary action required. The action required in my case is to launch the application i.e., app-1.

However, in my use case I don't want an additional app to start the app-1. Instead, the app-1 should be launched automatically when the button is clicked in mobile application. The wearOS application is similar to health tracking apps which should get automatically started(in my case with button click) on wearOS device when the user wants to track the activity.

FYI: The mobile and watch are connected via Bluetooth.

I tried using `RemoteActivityHelper` similar to what is suggested on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67707392/16114554) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69412208/how-to-start-companion-app-on-mobile-from-smartwatch-using-remoteintent) post. The posts linked talk about starting application on phone from wearOS device. I want the vice-versa.

I called the `startRemoteActivity` on `RemoteActivityHelper` when the button is clicked but the app-1 on my wearOS device didn't start. The code can be found below:

This is my code in my phone's button onClickListener method.

```
RemoteActivityHelper remoteActivityHelper = new RemoteActivityHelper(this, Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor());
    Uri uri1 = Uri.parse("eatmon2://mainactivity");
       Intent intentAndroid = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
                            .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE)
                            .setData(uri1);
       remoteActivityHelper.startRemoteActivity(intentAndroid, uri1.getHost());
```

This is the code which I wrote in my wearOS application AndroidManifest.xml.

```
    <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:exported="true">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                    <data android:scheme="eatmon2" android:host="mainactivity" />
                </intent-filter>
    
     <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
     </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Is it possible to achieve what I am trying to do ? Is there any way to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'd suggest reading this guide on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please share your code with the call to `startRemoteActivity`.

Comment: Thanks for the guide! I added the code to my question above.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved. The mistake which I was doing is by passing `uri1.getHost()` in place of node id. The fix to this was I replaced `uri1.getHost()` with `null`.

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/wear/remote/interactions/RemoteActivityHelper#startRemoteActivity(android.content.Intent,kotlin.String)),

`` For `targetNodeId` if null is given, and the current device is a watch, the activity will start on the companion phone device. Otherwise, the activity will start on all connected watch devices. ``

So by passing null to the node Id, my watch(which is connected to my phone via Bluetooth) application activity is started.

Now the code in my phone's button onClickListener method looks like:

```
RemoteActivityHelper remoteActivityHelper = new RemoteActivityHelper(this, Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor());
Uri uri1 = Uri.parse("eatmon2://mainactivity");
Intent intentAndroid = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
   .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE)
   .setData(uri1);
remoteActivityHelper.startRemoteActivity(intentAndroid, null);
```

There is no change in the wearOS application AndroidManifest.xml.